# Getting a hepatitis B vaccine when in Poland or Budapest

Tags: health, novice-travellers

I was a bit late on getting my hepatitis B vaccine before I left for my backpacking trip and I have to get 2 more shots, (1 month after 1st shot, 6 months after 1st shot ) and I'm wondering if anyone knows anywhere in Poland or Budapest that I would be able to get my second shot of it?

Thanks.

Comment: You may need the documentation of the first shot, in order to request the second/third shots. Note, however, that the 1-month and 6-month intervals are the _minimum_ recommended, and that the subsequent two can be resumed at any time, even years after.

Answer (score 2):

For the hepatitis B vaccine, the 1-month and 6-month intervals are the minimum recommended, and that the subsequent two can be resumed at any time, even years after. You may need to carry with you the documentation of the first shot, in order to request the second/third shots.

As the hepatitis B vaccine is mandatory in both Poland and Hungary, you would have to locate a medical facility or clinic which offer services to those not entitled to government-funded healthcare. Depending where you are, Internet searches for [medical care in Hungary](https://welovebudapest.com/en/2014/07/30/how-to-get-medical-care-in-budapest-emergencies-doctors-hospitals-and-more/) or [medical care in Poland](https://www.polska.pl/tourism/practical-information/access-medical-care-poland/) should start you in the right direction.

Comment: While it’s true that the series can be completed later, the OP probably started it because they wanted to be protected on the trip. For that, they need the second shot; according to the documentation for one vaccine (_Engerix-B_ – it should be similar for others), only 15% of people will be protected against infection one month after a single shot. The third shot is indeed less urgent, it mostly serves as a booster to make the protection permanent.